# How to send Internet service data to main activity?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a variable in FetchAddressIntentService class name addressText which holding zip code using reverse geocode. what i want is to send the addressText data to my MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your main activity to the broadcast and then send the broadcast from the service.

**In your main activity:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction("BROADCAST_ZIP_CODE");

  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //get data from the intent and display it
      String zipCode = intent.getStringExtra("ZIP_CODE");
      //do something with the zipCode
    }
  };
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}


 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  if (receiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   receiver = null;
  }
  super.onDestroy();
 }
```

**In your service:**

```
public class ZipCodeService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        String zipCode = "your_zip_code"; 
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("BROADCAST_ZIP_CODE");
        intent.putExtra("ZIP_CODE",zipCode);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

}

Comment: what to add on method  onReceive ? to get data

Comment: @user3218829, please read the Android documentation on how to retrieve data from Intents.

Comment: sorry my bad - address = intent.getStringExtra("ZIP"); like this

Comment: Look at my update at "**In your service:**" . In your service you have to call the **sendBroadcast**, whereas the receiver it is in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways.

1. Using a Bound Service and registering your Activity as a listener object with your Service by having your Activity implement a listener interface. Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).
2. Sending a Local Broadcast from the Service to your Activity. (See JackD's answer)

Depending on how you've architected your application you may prefer one solution more than the other. The Android docs will help which is best.